# jQuery DataTables edit cell in place with drop down select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, dropdown

I have a DataTables table coming from a database. I want to have a dropdown enabled when I select rows from the dataset. The dropdown will be populated with every option from that column.

It has been suggested that this be done using rowCallback, but I haven't been able to figure out how to create the editable fields for the columns by row once the checkbox is enabled.

The function, on select would cause that row's Class and Category cells to become dropdown menus populated with all of the existing options in Class and Category to choose from.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<script charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://editor.datatables.net/extensions/Editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="samples" class="display nowrap compact hover dt-left" width="100%"></table>
    </table>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="JS/datatables.js"></script>
</body>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready( function () {    
  var table = $('#samples').DataTable( { 
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "pageLength": -1,
    "lengthMenu": [[100, 250, 500, -1], [100, 250, 500, "All"]],
    ajax: "datatables.php",
    columns: [ 
      {data: '',
       defaultContent: '0',
       visible: false },
      {data: '',
       defaultContent: '',
       orderable: false,
       className: 'select-checkbox',
       targets:   1
      },
      {title : 'Sample Name', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 1},
      {title : 'Region/Program', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 2},
      {title : 'Class', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 3},
      {title : 'Category', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 4},
      {title : 'QC Concerns', 'className': 'dt-left', data: 5}
    ],
    select: {
        style:    'multi',
        },
    order: ([[ 4, 'asc' ], [ 5, 'asc' ], [ 3, 'asc' ]]),
    orderFixed: [0, 'desc'],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
     {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: '<span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span> Download (ALL) or (SELECTED)',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 2, 5 ],
                modifier: {
                    search: 'applied',
                    order: 'applied'
                }
            }
        },
         {
            text: 'Use Selected Library',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config) {
            alert( 'This buton needs to pass the Sample Name and Category columns to php.' );
            }

             },
         {
                text: 'Upload Predefined Library',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, conf ) {
                    alert( 'This button needs to allow a csv file to be uploaded and passed to php.' );
                }
         }

     ]
  } );

  table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    if ( type === 'row' ) {
        var row = table.row( dt );
        table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( '1' );
        table.draw();
    }
  });

  table.on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    if ( type === 'row' ) {
        var row = table.row( dt );
        table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( '0' );
        table.draw();
    }
  });

} );
```

Data sample

```
const srcData = [
    {Name: '752', Region: '7', Class : 'unknown', Category : 'unknown', QC_Concerns: 'yes'},
    {Name: 'North 5th', Region: 'NWA', Class : 'unknown', Category : 'square', QC_Concerns: 'yes'},  
    {Name: 'Elmdale', Region: '6', Class : 'back', Category : 'circle', QC_Concerns: ''},  
    {Name: 'Rosebud', Region: '7', Class : 'back', Category : 'triangle', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: 'Letterkenny', Region: 'GO', Class : 'back', Category : 'square', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: '632nd', Region: 'GO', Class : 'front', Category : 'ball', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: 'Water', Region: '4', Class : 'front', Category : 'ball', QC_Concerns: ''},
    {Name: 'Dirt', Region: '1', Class : 'front', Category : 'mermaid', QC_Concerns: ''},
    ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I failed to comprehend  your sample data structure, so I demonstrated the way of how it can be done, using my own:

```js
//table source data
const srcData = [{
    id: 1,
    item: 'apple',
    category: 'fruit'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    item: 'banana',
    category: 'fruit'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    item: 'carrot',
    category: 'vegie'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    item: 'raspberry',
    category: 'berry'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    item: 'potato',
    category: 'vegie'
  }
];
//DataTable initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    dom: 't',
    data: srcData,
    select: 'multi',
    columns: Object.keys(srcData[0]).map(key => {
      return {
        title: key,
        data: key
      }
    })
  });
//grab all the unique sorted data entries from the necessary row
const category = dataTable.column(2).data().unique().sort();
//Row click handler
dataTable.on('deselect', (event, row, type, index) => writeCell($(row.node()).find('select')));
dataTable.on('select', (event, row, type, index) => $(row.node()).find('td:eq(2)').html('<select>' + category.reduce((options, item) => options += `<option value="${item}" ${item == row.data().category ? 'selected' : ''}>${item}</option>`, '') + '</select>'));
//Drop down menu stop event propagation
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tbody td select', event => event.stopPropagation());
//Write dropdown value into table
var writeCell = dropdown => {
  const currentRow = dataTable.row(dropdown.closest('tr'));
  const rowData = currentRow.data();
  rowData.category = dropdown.val();
  currentRow.remove();
  dataTable.row.add(rowData).draw();
};
```

```css
tbody tr:hover {
  background: lightgray !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tbody tr.selected {
  background: gray !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is really close to what I am after. I need to be able to select multiple rows though.  (I updated my data block to match the format you are using.)  What is happening in my code is that two columns are being added to the front of the table in order to allow a checkbox and checkbox tracking. This allows any selected items to move to the top of the table.  Once they are selected, then the drop down becomes active. @yevgengorbunkov

Comment: I have fixed the code to allow multiple selection. Regarding checkboxes sorting and the rest - this is totally different topic and I encourage you not to try to address multiple issues at a time. So, accept the answer if it solves that particular problem, open the question for the next one with proper description and let me look into it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wasn't asking an additional question. I thought you were saying that you didn't understand the data structure because of the two columns I was adding to the front. So I was explaining what those columns do.

Comment: Than it's my fault, I misunderstood your explanation. So, as multiple selection works, your question is answered now?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to implement it with my existing code. I keep getting errors, even when I remove my select code that moves selected items to the top.  Is the data initialization chunk required to make it function, or can I sub in my existing data section?

Comment: You may skip DataTables initialization as you got your own, you just need to substitute in the rest my code `dataTable` for `table` due to different variable name and it should work just fine.

Comment: Would I need to change the on clicked action to on checked or on select?  Since my rows are selected via a select-checkbox?

Comment: This works on my server, but not on Codepen. (I am trying to use a generic ajax dataset in place of mine.)   And by "works" I mean that that selected rows move to the top, and the category field becomes a dropdown.  But the dropdown box is empty.  https://codepen.io/CrashVector/pen/oVOVKX

Comment: I should clarify, it works on my server when getting the data through my php script.  I'm not sure what I have done wrong here when pointing to the generic data that causes it not to load.

Comment: It somehow escaped my notice that you're using select extension (which provide extra options and events), while I was emulating selection for the sake of simplicity. I've adjusted my code to your environment.

Comment: I still have the select causing the dropdown to be empty.  The behavior before on deselect didn't trigger a deselct and would display a 1 over the checkbox.  Now it looks to be triggering the deselect and shows a 0 over the checkbox.  Not sure why it is showing those numbers.   Here is a link to the datatables forum where I've also been asking about this. There is a suggestion to use a different extension.  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/55331

Comment: I found a solution for the dropdown being empty. When you use an ajax import, the dropdown list is created before the table is loaded.  Adding a n initComplete line and placing the dropdown creation in a function solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to add the ddl on your 3rd column for all the values in that column.

```
 initComplete: function () { // After DataTable initialized
            this.api().columns([2]).every(function () {
                /* use of [2] for third column.  Leave blank - columns() - for all.
                Multiples? Use columns[0,1]) for first and second, e.g. */
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""/></select>')
                    .appendTo($('.datatable .dropdown .third').empty()) /* for multiples use .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() ) or .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() ) */
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                });
            }); // this.api function
        } //initComplete function

    });
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.datatable').removeAttr('style');
});
```